# Why did python suddenly get slow on my Mac?

Tags: python, performance, startup

```sh
$ time python -c "print()"


real    0m6.053s
user    0m0.030s
sys 0m0.018s
```

Why does it take 6 seconds for python to start on my machine? How can I begin debugging this? Once Python is running it's just as fast as it ever was, but most of the time startup takes seconds. Though it varies. Sometimes the startup time is quite quick.

Comment: You could run `python -v` (lowercase v) to turn on verbose import logging, then see if anything weird is getting imported on startup. This isn't really an appropriate question for Stack Overflow, though, since there's nowhere near enough information to diagnose the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
 ps -eff | grep python
```

to see if there are any stuck python processes. I hope this helps